# Creating a thread with Thread Class doesn't display the same result as in Progamming in C# Exam Ref 70-483

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to execute the following code from Programming in C# Exam Ref 70-483 and the books says that the result must be:

Main thread: Start a second thread.
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 0
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 1
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 2
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 3
ThreadProc: 4
ThreadProc: 5
ThreadProc: 6
ThreadProc: 7
ThreadProc: 8
ThreadProc: 9

And when I execute the same code in Visual Studio 2017 it displays me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd3sJ.jpg

```
public static void ThreadProc() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
        // Yield the rest of the time slice.
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
}

public static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Start a second thread.");
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
    t.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }


    t.Join();

}
```

Comment: I suppose the book was written when most CPUs had a single execution core, which made execution more predictable: since only one thread could run at a given time, and they each yielded to the other, you could guess the order of the messages. On a computer with multiple cores, the only assumption you can make is that `Main thread: Start a second thread.` will be displayed first. Everything else is unpredictable.

Comment: These books have a lot of bugs, an inevitable side-effect of printing code on dead wood.  Google "exam 70-483 errata" to find corrections.

Comment: @HansPassant i just download it to see other corrections, thank you :)